# Can I specify Queryable.GroupBy (instead of Enumerable.GroupBy) in query expression syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees, linq-query-syntax

When I write a `Group By` in query expression syntax, the compiler automatically picks `Enumerable.GroupBy` as my intended tareget method and I get an `IEnumerable` back instead of an `IQueryable`.  That means a subsequent `g.Sum` call (inside of my `Select`) expects a `Func(Of TSource, int)` instead of an `Expression(Of Func(Of TSource, int))`.  Is there a way to force the `Group By` to use `Queryable.GroupBy` instead and give me back an `IQueryable`?

**Contrived Sample Code**

```
Dim myQuery = From x In DataSource.Items
              Group By x.Key Into g = Group
              Select New With {
                  .Key = Key,
                  .RedItems = g.Sum(ItemsOfColor(Colors.Red)) '<== invalid because g.Sum expects a lambda
              }

Private Function PurpleItems(color As Integer) As Expression(Of Func(Of Item, Integer))
    Return Function(item) If(item.Color = color, 1, 0)
End Function
```

**Why would I want to do this?**
The compiler automatically converts between a lambda and an expression based on the target variable type (ie, both `Dim f As Func(Of String, Integer) = Function(x) x.Length()` and `Dim e As Expression(Of Func(Of String, Integer)) = Function(x) x.Length()` are valid) so there is no noticable difference in the code between an `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.

The problem is, LINQ to Entities (and I assume other db backed LINQ implementations) relies on expression trees to translate into SQL.  That means the `IEnumerable` lambda version *will not work* against an `IDbSet` as I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11679553/794234) old question.

Comment: Have you tried using `g.AsQueryable().Sum`?

Comment: @IronMan84, yes, it's not available as a function

Comment: What is the type of `DataSource.Items`?

Comment: @svick `IDbSet(Of Item)` which implements `IQueryable(Of Item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Queryable.GroupBy()` returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, where `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` implemens `IEnumerable<TSource>`, but not `IQueryable<TSource>`.

And I believe your code wouldn't work anyway, because `ItemsOfColor()` wouldn't be actually called. Instead, the EF would get an expression that calls `ItemsOfColor()`. And since it doesn't know that method, it would throw an exception.

Comment: Why should the type of `IGrouping` matter if I have an `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`?  Also, you're right, it does make a MethodCallExpression. Any way to force the method to call immediately (something like a C macro)?

Comment: @just.another.programmer Because `g` in your code represents that `IGrouping`, not `IQueryable` (though VB seems to do something weird, so `g` is actually just `IEnumerable`).

Comment: That makes sense, but how does the compiler know to translate everything into expressions if it's an `IEnumerable` not an `IQueryable`?  (like the `MethodCallExpression` causing my problem here, or the the `LambdaExpression` it makes when you pass a lambda)?

Comment: @just.another.programmer Because that `IEnumerable` is used inside an expression, so it doesn't matter that it's itself just `IEnumerable`, since the collection that contains it is `IQueryable`.

Comment: At *run time* I could see that making a difference, but AFAIK the translation to `Expression` happens at *compile time*.  When the compiler sees an `IEnumerable` calling a `Sum`, it expects a lambda so there should be no translation.

Comment: @just.another.programmer I'm talking just about compile time types. And when compiler sees the call to `Enumerable.Sum()` with a lambda inside which itself is *inside another lambda* and that outer is compiled as an expression, the inner lambda is also compiled as an expression.

Comment: Tracking that must make for an amazingly complex compilation process.  Thanks.