# Can I control what the .NET compiler automatically converts to expressions

Tags: vb.net, linq, compiler-construction

The VB compiler automatically converts lambda's to their `LambdaExpression` equivalents (eg in `Dim a As LambdaExpression = Function(x) x.Length`).  Until recently, I thought that feature *only* applied to lambdas, but then I found the same behavior on trying to pass the *result* of a method call as an argument to a method.  The compiler converted my call to a `MethodCallExpression` instead of making the call!

```
Dim myQuery = From x In DataSource.Items
              Group By x.Key Into g = Group
              Select New With {
                  .Key = Key,
                  .RedItems = g.Sum(ItemsOfColor(Colors.Red))
              }

Private Function ItemsOfColor(color As Integer) As Expression(Of Func(Of Item, Integer))
    Return Function(item) If(item.Color = color, 1, 0)
End Function
```

`RedItems` contains a `MethodCallExpression` to call `ItemsOfColor` with `Colors.Red` as an argument instead of a `LambdaExpression` with the *result* of the `ItemsOfColor` call as I would have expected.

THe question(s): Why does the compiler assume this is the behavior I want, and, is there any way to turn it off?

NOTE: This is the third question in a series which has slowly been helping me understand how  LINQ is compiled and the side effects thereof.  Part [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11679553/794234) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15949279/794234).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understand the problem... so here goes.  The query expression syntax (as above) makes it *appear* that `.RedItems = g.Sum(ItemsOfColor(Colors.Red))` is a normal method call, but **it's not**.  That "call" is actually inside the body of a lambda for the `Select` statement on the previous line.  Rewritten in lambda syntax, this would be:

```
.Select(Function(x) New With {
    .Key = Key,
    .RedItems = g.Sum(ItemsOfColor(Colors.Red))
})
```

Which highlights clearly that we're actually **inside** a lambda already.  The compilation step responsible for converting the lambda argument to `Select` to an expression tree sees the call to `ItemsOfColor` and creates a `MethodCallExpression`, exactly as we would expect!

In short, there is no special rule to convert a method call to an expression, it's actually a lambda, and my original questions are impossible in the current version of EF / LINQ.  Maybe one day MS will extend one of the two to recognize a `MethodCallExpression` which would produce an expression and make the call (thus making this type of refactoring a possibility).